Not receiving user_status_changed event
I am working with @slack/bolt, trying to get user_status_changed using Socket Mode. I can see messages when they come in but not when a user changes their status. I put myself in away or available and I never see that event.
Here just for developing I am waiting for all events. When I join a channel or message or just about anything I see a log. I just can't get the user_status_changed to show so I can use it.
// Listen for all events and log them
app.event(/.*/, async ({ event }) => {
    console.log('Received event:', event);
    if (event.type === 'user_status_changed') {
        const { user } = event;
        const presence = user.profile.presence;
        console.log(`Received user_status_changed event for user ${user.id}: ${presence}`);
        userPresence.set(user.id, presence);
        console.log(`User ${user.id} is now ${presence}`);
    }
    if (event.type === 'message') {
        console.log(`Received message event in channel ${event.channel}: ${event.text}`);
    }
    if (event.type === 'user_change') {
        const { user } = event;
        const presence = user.profile.presence;
        console.log(`Received user_status_changed event for user ${user.id}: ${presence}`);
        userPresence.set(user.id, presence);
        console.log(`User ${user.id} is now ${presence}`);
    }else{ console.log(event.type)}
});

I have gone through the docs and haven't found any answers to why this isn't working. I've even added every single scope permission to my bot for now to just blanket the issue.
